# List only private snapshot of AWS EBS volume through aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Hi I am trying to list only private snapshots of AWS EBS volumes through the AWS CLI and I couldn't find any reference online to proceed. Could experts please help?

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --query 'Snapshots[*].[SnapshotId,VolumeId,VolumeSize,StartTime,Description]' --region eu-west-2 --output json
```

Answer (score 2):

Since a private snapshot is one that is owned by you, you could limit the output to only be those that are owned by "self". Also, if you want the ones that are associated with a specific volume, then you can filter on that. For example:

`aws ec2 describe-snapshots --owner-ids self --filter Name=volume-id,Values=vol-060e26663d9fb1c67`

Of course, you'd want to replace the volume ID with your own.

Comment: Yes, `--owner-ids self` is almost always needed when listing snapshots. I wish it was the default!

Answer (score 1):

To adhere to best practises, watch out for large results. This can apply if you are working on larger architectures (i.e. many private snapshots).

I use use pagination to make the result sets easier to parse/use.

Example:

```
 aws ec2 describe-snapshots --query 'Snapshots[*].[SnapshotId,VolumeId,VolumeSize,StartTime,Description]' --region eu-west-2 --output json --max-results 20
```

Here I used `--max-results 20`.

For more information and AWS best practises regarding this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Query-Requests.html#api-pagination

(see "Query requests for Amazon EC2" and section "Pagination")